# Xcode can't attach to PyCharm debugging process

Tags: python, xcode, debugging, pycharm

I have a c++ library that I can debug in Xcode.
This library is 'bridged' to python via SWIG. I have some python code running, making calls to the library. In PyCharm I can debug the python version.

I would like to debug the c++ code that is called by the python function, using the Attach to Process feature of Xcode, in order to

1. check that the python call is correct, and
2. the arguments are passed as expected.

So, I start debugging the Python code from PyCharm, stop at a breakpoint (early) in the python code, identify the Python PID using `os.getpid()`, then in Xcode I try to attach to that process. However I get an error:

> "error: attach by pid '61889' failed -- attach failed (Not allowed to attach to process.  Look in the console messages (Console.app), near the debugserver entries when the attached failed.  The subsystem that denied the attach permission will likely have logged an informative message about why it was denied.)"

In the console I can't see any message about why it was denied.

Any idea? Is it a setting in PyCharm? In Xcode? In the system?

My setting: Mac OS 10.15, Xcode 12.4, PyCharm 2020.1; Python 3.7